# TypeError: Can't read property 'email' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use correct email and password it works fine.

But when email and password are incorrect, I get: `Can't read property 'email' of undefined` error. I want to handle it in the `if/else` section.

Please help. Thanks

```js
const {customers} = useContext(customersContext)
    const [customerEmail, setCustomerEmail] = useState("")

    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

    const history = useHistory();

    const currentUser = customers.find((s, index)=> s.email === customerEmail)

    const handleLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(currentUser.email === customerEmail && currentUser.password === password)
        {
            localStorage.setItem("customers", currentUser.id) 
            history.push("/home") 
            props.togle()  
        }
        else if(typeof currentUser.email === undefined)
        {
            window.alert("email does not match")
        }
        else {
            window.alert("No match found")
        }
    }
   
    return (
        <div>
            <Form>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="email">customerEmail</Label>
                    <Input type="email" name="email" onChange={(e) => setCustomerEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="password">Password</Label>
                    <Input type="password" name="password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button onClick={handleLogin}> Submit </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: If `customers.find(...)` doesn't return anything (giving it an incorrect email/password), then you can't use `currentUser.email`, as `currentUser` is `null`. A simple `if(!currentUser){ ... })` should help here :)

Comment: thank You Tim for replaying. I have used if(!currentUser) {window.alert("No match found")} but still the same error message

Comment: Well you have to prevent further execution; an alert does not do that. Somewhere in your `handleLogin()` function, you'll have to do `if(!currentUser){ ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

In general the logicals condition for `handleLogin` method may look so:

```js
if (currentUser === undefined) {
  window.alert("No match found")
// You shouldn't give a user a tip of what part in the login/password combination doesn't match, because it will make the brute forcing attempts way much easier
} else if (currentUser.email !== customerEmail || currentUser.password !== password) {
  window.alert("email or password does not match")
} else {
  localStorage.setItem("customers", currentUser.id) 
  history.push("/home") 
  props.togle()  
}
```

I hope that you **do not rely on this code on frontend**. Because it is **absolutely insecure** to verify logins and
passwords in this manner =)